# Sass not working using prefix

Tags: sass

Currently having a small issue.

Currently have a SCSS file which contains a series of styling preferences as shown below:

```
.login-scene {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}


.login-language {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.login-button {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

span.login-header {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
```

I then try to declare a prefix, and try to do the following:

```
$prefix: "login";

.prefix {
  &-scene {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
  }

  &-language {
      padding-top: 12px;
  }

  &-button {
      margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Im getting no errors in my application, but the styling isnt being applied once I have used a prefix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

answer is as follows.

```
$prefix: "login";

.#{$prefix} {
  &-scene {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
  }

  &-language {
      padding-top: 12px;
  }

  &-button {
      margin-top: 30px;
  }

}
```